# Use hadoop to fastly encode my videos

Tags: hadoop, video, ffmpeg

I'm developping a VOD plateform which get videos with the size > 2Gb so the conversion take too long and i want to use hadoop and ffmpeg to fastly encode my videos , is that possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is yes.

Pivotal have a blog post on how to do distributed video encoding using hadoop which is a good place to start

**[pivotal blog MR for video transcoding](http://blog.pivotal.io/data-science-pivotal/products/using-hadoop-mapreduce-for-distributed-video-transcoding)**

It is not the complete answer and is using mpeg-2, but if you already have the encoding working in a single thread.  then you should be pretty much good to go.